# Unable to get feed content with CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get the content of this feed :
http://www.institut-viavoice.com/viavoice-paris/publications/sondages-publies?format=feed&type=rss

Here is my code :

```
$url = 'http://www.institut-viavoice.com/viavoice-paris/publications/sondages-publies?format=feed&type=rss';

$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0",
CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10
);

$curl = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options ); 
$content = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);

echo $content;
```

I tried many other CURL options but it doesn't work.
As the content is accessible through my browser, I suppose it can be done with PHP. But what is wrong with my code ? It seems like there is an exception with the server of this feed ?

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't really helpful. What do you get? Any errors? Is error reporting on?

Comment: I get strictly nothing. No error and yes, error reporting is on...

Comment: I tried my code with some other feeds and the content was showing up. This feed is an exception and I don't understand why.

Comment: I tried the above code and it works on  my computer. Btw. You should just use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and remove `error_reporting(-1);` (the second call just overrides the first). This doesn't display the errors though, it just sets the reporting level. You need to add: `ini_set('display_errors', true);` to actually show the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, may be your breaking the cURL options and calling the URL.
Here a simple example, give it a try:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$content = get_data('http://www.institut-viavoice.com/viavoice-paris/publications/sondages-publies?format=feed&type=rss');

echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work... No error, blank screen...

Comment: Works fine at my end. Which Stack you are using? Also make sure you have enabled display errors in PHP

Comment: I try my code directly on the server of my host. Display error is enabled with `error_reporting(E_ALL); error_reporting(-1);`. Is that correct ? I don't understand why my code works with all my feeds (tens of them) except this one...

Comment: Well everything works fine at my side, you need to figure out what is wrong? Did you tried it on any other server?

Comment: Yes, I tried on three other servers of my host. So, I must assume that the problem is from my server hosting services.

Comment: Did this work at any point for you? Sometimes the connection is refused because the verify peer is not set explicitly to false. May want to try that in your CURL setopt.  Also, are you sure that the curl url is correct - and are you sending as a POST request or a GET?

Comment: So the issue is with your server. You can try the script i gave you and accept it as answer if its working for you on another servers. If you want i can show you a demo for that as well.

Comment: @SagarGulati : my problem is that it works with my code for all my feeds except 1 (on 25) and it doesn't work for me with your code for several of them... So, it doesn't seem to be a code problem.

Comment: @AdamT I tried `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false` but it still doesn't work. And concerning the sending, my code is exactly what you see in the first post : `$url`is actually a constant in my case.

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume I am thinking then it is a configuration issue as others have mentioned. Can you do a comparison of `phpinfo()` or (from command line) `php -i` or `php -r "phpinfo();"` ?

Comment: @AdamT Sorry, now it's beyond my skills... Here is the phpinfo answer.
http://imageshack.com/a/img922/7766/jGaiEC.png

Comment: And the answer is the same with this type of code : `$doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->load($url); $channels = $doc->getElementsByTagName('channel');`

Comment: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is only relevant if you're calling the URL through https.